# React Next JS dynamic css for grid-template and grid-area

Tags: css, reactjs, next.js, tailwind-css

Using Tailwind CSS, I have a grid with cards. Each card has a button and when pressed a child card opens up below the card in the grid. It is currently working with the below code but the css is limited as its not dynamic, would love to have a better less static way of achieving this, one that could scale to any amount of rows. The current approach is limited to 5 rows and any additional row would need to be accounted for manually.

```
.grid-container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template:
    ". . . . ."
    "A1 A1 A1 A1 A1"
    "A2 A2 A2 A2 A2"
    "A3 A3 A3 A3 A3"
    "A4 A4 A4 A4 A4"
    "A5 A5 A5 A5 A5"
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.grid-item {
  grid-column-end: span 5;
}

.grid-A1 {
  grid-area: A1;
}

.grid-A2 {
  grid-area: A2;
}

.grid-A3 {
  grid-area: A3;
}

.grid-A4 {
  grid-area: A4;
}

.grid-A5 {
  grid-area: A5;
}
```

I tried this but it never had the desired affect

```
.grid-A + i {
  grid-area: A + i;
}
```

My div looks like this to call the correct grid-area

```
 <div className={`grid-item grid-A${Math.floor(selected_cardIndex / 5) + 1}`}>
   <CardDetails
       data={details}
       showModal={showModal}
       isVisible={detailsVisible}
       handleBuy={handleBuy}
   />
 </div>
```

I have a mobile version too which is even more of a problem as it only has two columns so many more rows.

Comment: Could you provide a fuller example with the cards and the card details and the overall layout of the grid? You could consider using the `style` attribute instead of classes for fully dynamic values.

Comment: If each card <div> is spanning all 5 columns, why have a 5 column grid at all? In fact, why use grid when you could use flex or block for this layout?